# Query to search for the songs to contain all the requested tags

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, subquery

I am making a search engine for songs using tags, and I have trouble building the SQL query that will list all the songs that match with the tags.

The database looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Tuo.png

Songs have many Tags through an intermediate table(SongTags).

Let's have a population as example:

**Tags**:
Electro, Instrumental, Energetic, Melancholic, Vocal, Rock

**Songs**:
SongA (Electro, Melancholic, Vocal)
SongB (Instrumental, Melancholic, Rock)
SongC (Energetic, Vocal)

---

The search should return the songs that contains ALL the tags requested.

**Search1:**

"Vocal" returns: SongA, SongB

**Search2:**

"Vocal", "Energetic" returns: SongC

**Search3:**

"Vocal", "Energetic", "Electro" returns: nothing

---

I see how to do a search on 1 tag, but not on multiple tags.
For exemple for the Search1, I know that this would work:

```
SELECT * FROM "songs"
INNER JOIN "song_tags" ON "song_tags"."song_id" = "songs"."id"
INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "song_tags"."tag_id"
WHERE "tags"."name" = 'Vocal'
```

But then I have no idea on how I could execute Search2, because I need the Song to contain both "Vocal" and "Energetic".

Edit:

I am using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT songs.*, COUNT(songs.id) AS total FROM "songs"
INNER JOIN "song_tags" ON "song_tags"."song_id" = "songs"."id"
INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "song_tags"."tag_id"
WHERE "tags"."name" IN ('Vocal', 'Energetic')
GROUP BY songs.id
HAVING total = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get songs that match *all* the tags you are provided, I'd use subselects. They'll be a little bit slow, but it'll give you an all-matched solution:

```
SELECT songs.* FROM songs
  WHERE songs.song_id IN
    (SELECT song_tags.song_id FROM song_tags st JOIN tags t ON st.tag_id = t.id AND t.name = 'VOCAL')
   AND songs.song_id IN (SELECT song_tags.song_id FROM song_tags st JOIN tags t ON st.tag_id = t.id AND t.name = 'ENERGETIC')
```

If your SQL server supports the INTERSECT command, you could do this:

```
SELECT songs.* FROM songs
  WHERE songs.song_id IN
    (SELECT song_tags.song_id FROM song_tags st JOIN tags t ON st.tag_id = t.id AND t.name = 'VOCAL' 
    INTERSECT
   SELECT song_tags.song_id FROM song_tags st JOIN tags t ON st.tag_id = t.id AND t.name = 'ENERGETIC')
```

which I think is a cooler way to do it.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but archana's answer is more efficient :)
Cheers !

Comment: Hmm... I think it is, too... but as I understand it, IN is not a full match query - I think it will match *either* of the tags, which means you'll get a list of songs that are Vocal **OR** Energetic, but not necessarily both.

Comment: THe 'HAVING total = 2' statement at the end makes it an AND statement, think about it again.

Comment: Be interesting to run comparisons of the two methods, and see what the execution plans and efficiencies are like.